# Python : Using abc in Python < 2.6

Tags: python, abc, backport

Do someone know an implementation of [abc](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html) for older versions of Python (older than 2.6) ?

EDIT : I am for example looking for a snippet that would do the same thing as ABCMeta and abstractmethod, with same interface, I actually need to make a piece of code backward compatible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **abc** module itself happens to be backwards compatible.  Just copy abc.py from 2.6 to somewhere on the pythonpath.